# Magento 2 REST API Add Single Customer Address

Tags: magento2, rest-api

Can anyone mention the Jason payload to add new address in existing customer.

yes its a shipping address

> How to add new Address using REST API, While placing an order.

Comment: Arsalan, if any answer helps you then you mark accepted to those answer, so it will helpful for future readers, you can mark accept answer by clicking (✓) next to answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $addresss = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory');
        $address = $addresss->create();

        $address->setCustomerId($customerId)
            ->setFirstname($firstName)
            ->setLastname($lastName)
            ->setCountryId($countryCode)
            ->setPostcode($postCode)
            ->setCity($city)
            ->setTelephone($telephone)
            ->setFax($fax)
            ->setCompany($company)
            ->setStreet($street)
            ->setIsDefaultBilling('0')
            ->setIsDefaultShipping('0')
            ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');

        if($address->save()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
```

> { "data": { "cust_id": x, "email": "XXX@gmail.com", "first_name":
>   "xxx", "last_name": "xxx", "region_code": "xxx", "country_id": "xx",
>   "street": [ "road4" ], "telephone": "xxxxxxx", "postcode": "xxxx",
>   "city": "xxxxx", "company":"", "fax":"", "default_shipping": "1",
>   "default_billing": "1" } }

Answer (score 1):

First make a `GET` request to `{{host}}/rest/{{store_code}}/V1/customers/me`.

If the `addresses` nodes contains an array of address objects these need to be sent with the next request otherwise the addresses will be deleted from the customer's account. Tok keep the existing addresses they must be sent with the ID that was returned in the original request. You should also send all the existing data in the address object otherwise the address will be updated.

Next make a `PUT` request to the same URL with a request body like:

```
{
    "customer": {
        "email": "name@email.com",
        "firstname":"John",
        "lastname":"Doe",
        "website_id": 1,
        "addresses": [
            {
                "firstname": "John",
                "lastname": "Doe",
                "street": [
                  "123 Some Street",
                  "Additional street if necessary"
                ],
                "city": "Some City",
                "postcode": "AB1 2CD",
                "country_id": "GB",
                "telephone": "077777777777",
                "default_billing": true,
                "default_shipping": true,
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand form your question you need to add shipping address while placing an order from REST API

You can use shipping-information API

**Get & put Shipping Information.**

```
http://magento-host/index.php/rest/V1/carts/mine/shipping-information
```

- `method : POST`
- `Authorization : Bearer <customer token>`
- `body data : json`

---

```
{
    "addressInformation": {
        "shippingAddress": {
            "region": "MH",
            "region_id": 0,
            "country_id": "IN",
            "street": [
                "221,Baker-street (e)"
            ],
            "company": "Lumos",
            "telephone": "12345678",
            "postcode": "400001",
            "city": "Mumbai",
            "firstname": "Aditya",
            "lastname": "Shah",
            "email": "Aditya@Shah.com",
            "prefix": "address_",
            "region_code": "MH",
            "sameAsBilling": 1
        },
        "billingAddress": {
            "region": "MH",
            "region_id": 0,
            "country_id": "IN",
            "street": [
                "221,Baker-street (e)"
            ],
            "company": "Lumos",
            "telephone": "12345678",
            "postcode": "4000001",
            "city": "Mumbai",
            "firstname": "Aditya",
            "lastname": "Shah",
            "email": "Aditya@Shah.com",
            "prefix": "address_",
            "region_code": "MH"
        },
        "shipping_method_code": "flatrate",
        "shipping_carrier_code": "flatrate"
    }
}
```

---

Comment: but this doesn't show up baseurl/rest/V1/customers/me/ address

Comment: pass "saveInAddressBook": 1, in both array.

Comment: no still i don't get

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/8TDChfT   is this correct

Comment: Have you checked what is missing